# Can't style disabled option in html select

Tags: html, css

Despite following the [example from w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_disabled_option), I can't style my disabled option:

```
<select id="state-handle">
  <option value="" selected="true" disabled>State of residence</option>
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
</select>

option {
  color: blue;
}

option:disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tdc1vu4/)

No red anywhere:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I did the same thing as they do.

EDIT: my config is Windows 10 / Google Chrome (same result using Firefox on my machine)

Comment: The fiddle works here, at least under Linux; it might be different in other OSes.

Comment: Red color is applied for me on windows 10, Chrome.

Comment: By the way, the highlight colors override the default colors, which might confuse things. Hover your mouse over the USA part.

Comment: What is your js version? as l too can see red!

Comment: Look this similar thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element

Answer (score 0):

Your styles are valid, but your can remove `selected="true"` from your disabled option in order to see it.